# Return statment not working in Java

Tags: java, generics, recursion

I have been trying a small code to learn about recursion in java. Wrote the below method to implement linear search using recursion. But when I call this method with an array and the variable to search as input and when the method reaches the return statement, it is not exiting the method. Instead, after executing the statements in the if loop, it's once again entering the else loop.

I have 2 questions.

1) Why is it not exiting the method on reaching 'return' ?

2) Why is it entering the else loop after executing the if loop ?

What am I doing wrong here ? Can someone please take a look and help me.

```
linearRecursiveSearch(Constants.INPUT_INT_ARRAY, Constants.INPUT_INT_ARRAY[0], Constants.NUMBER_TO_SEARCH); 



int count = 0;
public <T> void linearRecursiveSearch(T[] array,T tmp, T value) {
    count++;
    if (tmp == value) {
        System.out.println("The value has been found");
        return;
    } else {
        for (int i = count; i < array.length; i++) {
            T tmp1 = array[i];
            linearRecursiveSearch(array,tmp1, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A debugger would be immensely helpful to you here - have you tried using one?

Comment: `if` and `else` are not loops.

Comment: You will need to return something (not `void`) and check this value in your loop to exit your loop if needed by using `break` or `return`.

Comment: What are the values passed to the function which are making it fail?

Comment: and your loop looks a bit not fitting in there. On each iteration it will go into the method again and check the from `count - array.length -1`. But it will seach for the element until `array.length-1` in every case, since the other inovcations of `linearRecursiveSearch` are still looping to the end.

Comment: Also, you almost definitely want to use `tmp.equals(value)` (or `Objects.equals(tmp, value)`) instead of `==`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Why is it not exiting the method on reaching 'return' ?

It is exiting the method that invoked `return`.

> 2) Why is it entering the else loop after executing the if loop ?

The method that invoked `return` is not invoking the else loop.  However there are other invocations of the method that are, and they are queued up to resume after the method that does invoke `return` completes.

---

The point of confusion is that there is more than one invocation of the method and they are not all calling return.

Perhaps it will help to recall what happens when a method invocation occurs,  that is the state of the current method is pushed onto a stack.  Space is then reserved on the stack for the new invocation and then that method is invoked.  Once that method completes, its state is popped from the stack.  Its return value is made available and the previous method that is now at the top of the stack is resumed.

During recursion, the same method may be pushed on to the stack hundreds of times.  That means the method could be called hundreds of times, and then each method will be resumed hundreds of times as the stack unwinds.  Thus just because the method that is currently being invoked calls return (and exits) it does not mean that all of the other queued up instances will too.   In fact it actually means that the previous method (the one that called this method) will resume.

---

Consider the following version, notice that it does not contain a for loop or any global state:

```
public <T> int linearRecursiveSearch(T[] array, T targetValue) {
    return linearRecursiveSearch( array, targetValue, 0 );
}

private <T> int linearRecursiveSearch(T[] array, T targetValue, int i) {
    if ( i >= array.length ) {
        return -1;
    } else if (array[i] == targetValue) {  
        // == or .equals, or Comparator?  task for the reader
        return i;
    } else {
        return linearRecursiveSearch(array, targetValue,i+1);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem this may be the solution

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.junit.Test

@Slf4j
class MyTest {
@Test
public void myTest(){
    int count = 0;
    Integer[] input= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    linearRecursiveSearch(input,5,0)
}

public <T> void linearRecursiveSearch(T[] array, T value,int count) {
    count++;
    if (array[count] == value) {
        System.out.println("The value has been found");
        return;
    } else {

            linearRecursiveSearch(array, value,count);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What happens if the value is not in the array?

Comment: This is not terminating but you can easily stop the recursion if count reach the size of the array. This was just and example on how to refactor the code in order to have a clean recursion. `if(count<array.length) linearRecursiveSearch(array, value,count);`